# RPI FAT32 Filesystem?

Tags: boot, sd-card, driver, partition

Is it possible to make the filesystem of the pi, which is normally EXT, to a FAT32, and the pi would still be able to use it? It would be very handy, cause then i would be able to edit the files for the pi on any computer... Now only the boot partition is FAT32. Is the pi able to use a FAT32 partition as filesystem, and if so, how? I understand that i would have to reformat the sd IF it's possible but that would not be a problem.

Thanks
Evert

Comment: Can't you just access and edit the files over the network instead (assuming your pi has some kind of network)?  Then you can "edit the files for the pi on any computer" if it's on the same network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible, Unix like system relies on standards that are not implemented in FAT or NTFS. Your system need permissions, groups, symbolic links to work properly. Neither FAT nor NTFS can provide it.